# Image doesnt refresh after PHP redirection (cache issue?)

Tags: php, javascript, html

the problem is the next: I am at main.php where I call a php file, with a JavaScript script, to synchronize the user's image with a new one on the server. But after all the file functions finish (with no problem) and I redirect with a header to the main.php, a very fast refresh is made but the image is not updated, I keep watching the old file but if I refresh the page with <kbd>F5</kbd> the new image is shown.

Cache problem? I have tried with some HTML meta tags but no luck. Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: In order to make it clear. I have tried with headers and with a timestamp in the redirection, but no luck. Here is the process:

1. main.php, once user click on his/her image a redirection with javascript (location.href) to update.php is launched.
2. I get a new image from the server, and save it overwriting the previous one (so the name is the same)
3. I add some headers to the code, no chae headers... and Location header redirecting again to main.php and I pass some parameter via GET also a timestamp (time()).
4. I reach the main.php but the reload is rarely fast and the new image is not shown.

Now I think is much clearer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a load balancer, proxy, a caching system on the server, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is cache issue, IE usually does that. I use the always append ?timestamp to the request to avoid such scenarios.

**EDIT:**

Yes i got it. I had same issue some time ago. Either way time stamp is the solution.

You have to add time stamp to <img src="path_to_image/image.jpg***?edited-time-stamp***" />

It worked for me, hope that works for you too.

Comment: I have also tried this but with no luck. I have added some info in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a lot, with the time stamp in the image request it worked perfect.

Comment: @Datenshi, happy to help stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You could add something like `?t=foo` to the URL of the picture. Where `foo` is a random string or number. Or maybe the current timestamp. That will make the browser request a completely new image and no caching instance will do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to add the header `Expires` or `Cache-Control` using the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function

Comment: I have tried it but with no luck. I have added some info in the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try out this method hope it helps you.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Location:http://www.test.com");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I have tried but with no luck. I have added some info in the question. Thanks for your help.